# Instagram style Listview in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am experimenting on creating Instagram style of listview in Flutter, where the top horizontal scrolling is of stories and the scroll section right below is a vertical one for the posts. I am just using a listview now and not a listview builder. But I somehow do not get the vertical scrolling in my output. Also, in the upper listview, the container size takes the size 100 of the parent container but not the height 80. How do I fix that?

Here is the code for :

```
body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 100,
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 80,
                  height: 80,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 80,
                  height: 80,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 80,
                  height: 80,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      )
```

And here is my output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this code below.

```
Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 100,
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 80,
                    height: 80,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 80,
                    height: 80,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 80,
                    height: 80,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 80,
                    height: 80,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 80,
                    height: 80,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 80,
                    height: 80,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 80,
                    height: 80,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 180,
                child: ListView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I get the "overflowing RenderFlex" error. I'm a beginner myself don't know what the cause is.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I still have one final issue with the upper horizontal scrolling. How can I achieve a padding of 10 from each side so that the containers of listview of height and witdh 80 can be arranged neatly. Because in the upper listview, the containers size takes the size 100 of parent container but not the height 80.

Comment: ```Padding(   
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0), 
 child: Container(), 
) ```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap vertical `List View` with an `Expanded` widget.

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: [
    Container(
      height: 100,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 80,
            height: 80,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 80,
            height: 80,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 80,
            height: 80,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 10,
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

Comment: There is no point setting `shrinkWrap` to `true` while using an `Expanded` widget and vice versa.

Comment: @Hamed Thank you guys. This worked pretty nicely. Of course to make the list dynamic I am gonna have to do with the builder way. Just experimenting here and there, I'm new. Thanks again!

Comment: @void Seems I can't tag two people in the same comment. But thanks anyways!

Comment: @void What to do if I want the horizontal scroll section to scroll along with vertical scrolling? Thanks!